# Is there anyway to call PubChem API In python?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, chemistry, pubchem

I have been using PubChem API to convert Chemical smiles to the structure but still have an error.

Here is my google colab I try with  PIL image plus TKinter

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TE9WxXwaWKSLQzKRQoNlWFqztVSoIxB7

My desired output should be in structure format like this

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/smiles/O=C(N1C=CN=C1)N2C=CN=C2/PNG?record_type=2d&image_size=large

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/mcs07/PubChemPy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and display in a Jupyter Notebook

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from IPython.display import Image

smiles = 'NC1=NC(C)=C(C2=CC=C(S(=O)(C)=O)C(F)=C2)S1'
urlretrieve('https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/smiles/'+smiles+'/PNG', 'smi_pic.png')
p = Image(filename='smi_pic.png')
p
```

Output

[image: structure]